# Read only column names using python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a excel file (Can be any type from csv,xsls,xslb) which can be very large (may be 500 mb) . I only want to get the column names from the file . Now I tried using pandas and get only column names ,but internally it seems to read or load the entire file which takes approx 1 minute . I don't want to load the entire file in memory and just want to read the column names .What is the best approach which I can use in order to avoid pandas to read the entire file and read and load only column names .
Is there a way where I can read the column names only without loading or reading the whole file as pandas by default seems to internally read/load the entire file . For example I used the below code to read xlsb file but it still takes a huge time (approx 1.5 min plus to get column names of file with size 17.9 mb)

```
filePath = "/Users/aj/testing/File_1.xlsb"
cols=pd.read_excel(filePath, engine='pyxlsb', index_col=0, nrows=0).columns.tolist()
```

This seems to load the entire file as I see reading the file and reading just column name takes same time

Comment: `nrows` needs to be 1. its number of rows, not index. I think nrows=0 is ignored

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using pandas read_excel method and then defining nrows to just include the first couple of rows? Won't that speed it up?

Comment: I used cols=pd.read_excel(filePath, engine='pyxlsb', index_col=0, nrows=0).columns.tolist() ...it still takes the same time to read just column names or I am using it wrong way .

Comment: try change nrows to 10. See what happens...

Comment: Just Tried ..it still takes same time .
cols=pd.read_excel(filePath, engine='pyxlsb', index_col=0, nrows=10).columns.tolist()